# Insecure login error while login with facebook php

Tags: php, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am doing login with Facebook using the Javascript SDK on a PHP website.

On localhost it works fine but with the live site url it gives me this error message:

> Insecure Login Blocked: You can't get an access token or log in to this app from an insecure page. Try re-loading the page as https://

Comment: Changed quoted error message to use a blockquote rather than code formatting because it was breaking on the single quote.

Comment: I imagine that the Facebook API permits insecure logins for local development environments just to help make things easy. It says you need to have your live environment running under https - are you sure it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have installed SSL Certificate on your site.
You can use open source [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/)

Comment: thanks. Also i noted that these has been new alterations from facebook since 2017 or 2018. This was not there before. So, now onwards for newly created facebook app we have to force it to https://. For old apps it works.

Comment: Also in ,my localhost it working because it was old created app, so it did not force me for https://

Comment: Queries from localhost are allowed without using the HTTPS protocol for easy software development.
If we transfer the project to the server, Facebook API requires an SSL certificate to ensure data security.