# Insecure Login Blocked: You can't get an access token or log in to this app from an insecure page. Try re-loading the page as https://

Tags: https, passport.js, facebook-authentication, passport-facebook

I am implementing Passport Facebook Authentication by linking the Facebook Authentication API route to a button using href like:

```
<a href="auth/facebook">Facebook Login</a>
```

When I click on the button, it redirects to the Facebook Authentication page. But on the page, an error message is displayed saying something like ***"Insecure Login Blocked: You can't get an access token or log in to this app from an insecure page. Try re-loading the page as https://"***

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: if you have created your facebook app after March 2018, now you are forced to use Https only, however, I'm still unclear about localhost. Anyway, it should fairly easy to generate an SSL for your localhost.

Comment: this may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49358800/insecure-login-error-while-login-with-facebook-php

Comment: If you are on localhost you can use ngrok to foward your localhost to https on the web

Answer (score 20):

Amazingly I just started trying to do the same thing like an hour ago and have been having the same issue.  If you go into the FB developer portal and go to **Settings** under **Facebook Login** there's an option to Enforce HTTPS.

[image]

*Further Investigation Showed*:

"Enforce HTTPS. This setting requires HTTPS for OAuth Redirects and pages getting access tokens with the JavaScript SDK. All new apps created as of March 2018 have this setting on by default and you should plan to migrate any existing apps to use only HTTPS URLs by March 2019. Most major cloud application hosts provide free and automatic configuration of TLS certificates for your applications. If you self-host your app or your hosting service doesn't offer HTTPS by default, you can obtain a free certificate for your domain(s) from Let's Encrypt."

Reference: [Login Security](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security/#surfacearea)

Comment: Here is the page provided by Let's Encrypt regarding certificates for a localhost: https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificates-for-localhost/

Comment: How can I use facebook login in localhost

Comment: And the button is disabled (March 2018). You're forced to use HTTPS under any circumstances. [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49553138/how-to-make-browser-trust-localhost-ssl-certificate/49553299#49553299) will help you set up SSL certificate for localhost. Or your custom domain.

Comment: @PranavPinarayi have you solved this problem about using facebook login in localhost?

Answer (score 5):

Since you're using `passport`, also check your `auth.js` settings, or where ever you keep these settings. **Even if your website has a certificate**, the following code will still fail:

```
'facebookAuth' : {
  'clientID'      : '.............', // App ID
  'clientSecret'  : '............................', // App Secret
  'callbackURL'   : 'localhost:9999/auth/facebook/callback',
  'profileURL'    : 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me?fields=first_name,last_name,email',
  'profileFields' : ['id', 'email', 'name'] 
},
```

The problem lies with the `callbackUrl`.

```
'callbackURL'   : '/auth/facebook/callback'
'callbackURL'   : 'http://localhost:9999/auth/facebook/callback'
```

The statements above will both fail. The callbackUrl needs to start with `https`. The first one will try to load `http://localhost` and append the callbackUrl. The second one obiviously loads the full url with `http`, and both fail to connect with FB. So try one of the following. If your site has a certificate, provide the full url. If you're testing this on a localhost, create your own certificate and access it by https like:

```
'callbackURL'   : 'https://example.com/auth/facebook/callback'
'callbackURL'   : 'https://localhost:9999/auth/facebook/callback'
```

Answer (score 3):

Since Facebook have been requiring usage of HTTPS for our redirect URIs we can use ngrok at localhost for start up a local secure HTTP tunnel. It is a clean and fast suggested alternative for now.

- Get [official ngrok package](https://ngrok.com/download)
- Unzip to your preferred directory
  `unzip /opt/ngrok.zip`;
- Make your first HTTP tunnel: `/opt/ngrok http 3000`

See more great use cases in [ngrok docs](https://ngrok.com/docs).

Comment: Thanks Lindoélio. I like this solution, but couldn't get it to work. I created a tunnel to http 3001, and then took the URL that ngrok produced, https://c5c35cb6.ngrok.io and put it in my redirect uri's, but I'm still getting the same error. 

Any other ideas?

Comment: EDIT:
Okay, it works if I go to the ngrok url (e.g.  https://c5c35cb6.ngrok.io). However, my site is so slow it's barely usable ...

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 ways you can solve that:
First:
You can go to your google Passport strategy and add proxy: true

```
    passport.use(
  new FacebookStrategy(
    {
      clientID: facebookID,
      clientSecret: facebookSecret,
      callbackURL: "/auth/facebook/callback",
      proxy: true
    }
  )
);
```

What happens most of the time is that, when you deploy or app through Heroku, for example, they have a Proxy that allows Heroku to direct the requests to your specific server and Passport assumes that if your request goes through a proxy it might not be safe (So... No https).
The second way you can solve that is by using a specific path for your callbackURL.
For example, instead of using:

```
callbackURL: "/auth/facebook/callback"
```

you would use:

```
callbackURL: https://mydomain/auth/facebook/callback
```

Keep in mind that if you are going to use this approach you might need to create environment variables to hold the values of your specific redirectURL for development as well as for production.

Comment: Thanks. This helped in 2020.. I am working on glitch.me

Comment: Thanks. This saved a lot of headache, still working in 2023, I was deploying on fly.io

Answer (score 1):

To fix, for local development, generate ssl certs on your machine. Run the commands below(tested on Mac High Sierra, you will need the openssl lib installed on your os) to create a `cert.pem` and a `key.pem` file in your working directory.

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout keytmp.pem -out cert.pem -days 365

openssl rsa -in keytmp.pem -out key.pem
```

Change your node http server to use https. You will need to import the `https` module in place of the `http` module.

```
const https = require('https')
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')
const options = {
  cert: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '<path_to_your_cert.pem>')),
  key: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '<path_to_your_key.pem>'))
}
const server = https.createServer(options, <your_handler_or_app_eg_express>)
server.listen(<your_prefered_port_number>)
```

Go to the app on your facebook developer console and set the Valid OAuth Redirect URIs to the https version of your localhost domain. Do same for the app domain and site url.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I modified my package.json file.

```
"start": "node scripts/start.js" => 
"start": "set HTTPS=true&&node scripts/start.js"
```

I hope help you.

Answer (score 0):

**This for php sdk reference**

Now **https is required for the web-application to login via Facebook**.

Following procedure is required get valid authentication from Facebook.

**Basic Seetings**

1. set **App Domains** as your root domain (*www.example.com*)
2. Privacy Policy URL (*https://www.example.com/privacy-demo/*)
3. Terms of Service URL (*https://www.example.com/terms-demo/*)
4. Set Category
5. Site URL  (*https://www.example.com/facebook-login/*) `facebook-login` this folder contain my all facebook login files

   **Advanced**
6. Server IP Whitelist (your host ip address *124.25.48.36*)

**Products below Facebook login settings**

7. Valid OAuth Redirect URIs (*https://www.example.com/facebook-login/fb-callback.php*)

**Quick start**

8. Select website put site url (*https://www.example.com/facebook-login/*)

Save all changes and live your app (ie: on your app) Now your app status will live.

You can refer this code https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk

Comment: What would you suggest for http?

Answer (score 0):

use a vpn worked for me cyber ghost is free try it

Answer (score 0):

In your passport setting change your redirect url to some **https://someUrl**
'https' is important

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to run localhost in an https environment while using flask, for example when testing integrations using OAUTH, here are several ways to do it: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/running-your-flask-application-over-https .

I'm using the first one, and even though Chrome gives me a warning, it allows me to ignore it.

Now quoting Miguel in case the link stops working:

> Flask, and more specifically Werkzeug, support the use of on-the-fly certificates, which are useful to quickly serve an application over HTTPS without having to mess with certificates. All you need to do, is add ssl_context='adhoc' to your app.run() call. As an example, below you can see the "Hello, World" Flask application from the official documentation, with TLS encryption added:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(ssl_context='adhoc')
```

> This option is also available through the Flask CLI if you are using a Flask 1.x release:

`flask run --cert=adhoc`

> To use ad hoc certificates with Flask, you need to install an additional dependency in your virtual environment:

`pip install pyopenssl`