# OpenSSL self signed certificate entirely blocked

Tags: ssl, https, openssl, certificate

I create self-signed certificate now my problem is Firefox,Safari and even IE will not allow me at all to visit my own page. I can't even click on ignore or similar. It will just block me from visiting mypage.io.

```
MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_SELF_SIGNED_CERT certificate is not valid for 81.33.34.123 (fake ip)
```

My openssl certificate key and crt creation was like this:

```
sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -out cert.crt
```

It prompts me to enter some more detail, and I think the problem is where it asks me about "Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name)".  I answered with `www.mypage.io` .
It's an unfinished project so I will not buy a certificate yet.

Answer (score 1):

The trust is missing!

Please get a real certificate. You do net even have to buy on: https://letsencrypt.org/ provides them for free.

If you (for whatever reason) stick with your certificate:

- IE: Import it to the trusted root certificate authority store (`certlm.msc`).
- Mozilla: [Look here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1059377)

Alternatively please find information on how to generate your own trust chain with open SSL here: [How to make browser trust localhost SSL certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49553138/how-to-make-browser-trust-localhost-ssl-certificate)

Comment: Letsencrypt is great, but when developing, I often have to regenerate certificates many times, and thus hit the letsencrypt's limits. One can bypass these limits by using the "break my certs" option, but then that leaves us with the OPs issue.