# How do I fix this: Your connection isn't private

Tags: python, .htaccess, pythonanywhere

When I try to enter my webpage I get this in Chrome and Edge.

I have the https.

[security](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0RBJ.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DjaW.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make browser trust localhost SSL certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49553138/how-to-make-browser-trust-localhost-ssl-certificate)

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure a certificate for your web app. Under the "Security" section on your web app configuration page.

Comment: Did that at pythonanywhere.

Comment: My bad. Everything was ok, Just forgot "www" in front of the domane. Thanks for the help. best regards RIJ