# Facebook login in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, facebook-login

I'm using facebook-sdk-codeigniter library for login with facebook few days back it was worked well now it shows

> Insecure Login Blocked: You can't get an access token or log in to this app from an insecure page. Try re-loading the page as https://

```
$config['facebook_app_id']              = '';

$config['facebook_app_secret']          = '';

$config['facebook_login_type']          = 'web';

$config['facebook_login_redirect_url']  = 'facebook_login';

$config['facebook_logout_redirect_url'] = 'logout';

$config['facebook_permissions']         = array('public_profile', 'publish_actions', 'email');

$config['facebook_graph_version']       = 'v2.6';

$config['facebook_auth_on_load']        = TRUE;
```

Comment: check [this reference url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49403748/insecure-login-blocked-you-cant-get-an-access-token-or-log-in-to-this-app-from?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: i have changed my domain  from http to https but still not working..